# Printing a Double properly on the native side of an android app

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, double, format-specifiers

I have an ndk method:

```
#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

_getDecimalDouble4(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jdouble doubleval)
{
    LOGD("NDK:LC: Native double [%E]", doubleval);
}
```

The output for the input `1.23456789128E8` always seems to be:

```
"NDK:LC: Native double [6.138557E-314]"
```

How do I display the exact value ?

Comment: On Android, "jdouble" is equivalent to "double".  How is this function declared in your Java code?

Comment: `private native void getDecimalDouble4(Double value);`

Comment: Change `Double` to `double` (capitalization).  One is an object, one is a double-precision floating point value.